# Windows search for executable which can exist in multiple subfolders, then run each instance, must be python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a script which runs on multiple servers. It searches for a process and calls taskkill to kill the process.

Each server may or may not have the same executable located in subfolders off a main folder. I am trying to search for this executable and launch it from each sub folder.

The taskkill works and the search locates the file and the location is held in memory as I can print out the path to the executable but I cant run the executable???? I don't get an error and the print statements I have put in to trace the process seem to be saying all the right things

```py
import os
import time
import ctypes
import subprocess
import sys, traceback

appName='calc.exe'
filePath = 'c:\dump'
print('\n' + 'Success line 8')

os.system("taskkill /f /im %appname")
time.sleep( 10 )
print('\n' + 'Success After Kill')

def getFileNameandTargetRootDirectory(fileName, rtDir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rtDir): 
        for f in files:
            if f.lower() == fileName.lower():
                print('Matched File Name: '+f)
                print('Path: '+os.path.join(root, f))
                print('\n')
                process=subprocess.Popen(['\'' +os.path.join(root, f) + '\''])
                #os.system(['\'' +os.path.join(root, f) + '\''])
                print('\n' + 'Success')

def main():
    getFileNameandTargetRootDirectory(appName, filePath)
if __name__=='__main__':
    print('IM HERE')
    main()
    print('\n' + 'Process finished')
```

Expected is a kill of the process, then a relaunch from each individual folder.

Kill works but no error on the launch but no launch

Comment: Can you try without the backslashes, i.e., `process=subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(root, f)])`

Comment: Thanks for that... that did work but managed to trace it in the end to running as localsystemuser as opposed to logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that... that did work but managed to trace it in the end to running as localsystemuser as opposed to logged in user